# Excel: deleting character converts it instead

Tags: microsoft-excel

I get this behaviour when trying to erase a character in Excel. It smells like a unicode-issue, but I have other cells that do not replicate this behaviour. I am looking for why it happens and how I can solve it.

[image]

Comment: To get clear on this, when you try to backspace the character `ä`, it instead converts the character to `a`? And in your gif you're pressing backspace a second time to delete the `a`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening.